# Generate data with Fakeit

Tags: nosql, couchbase, generate, fakeit

I'm using fakeit to generate data, but when I type the command "fakeit console user.yaml" I got this error below. I don't know what the problem is.

I searched about it on net but I didn't find the solution for this issue.

```
  ✖ Models (0/1)
    [13:35:11] ✖ error: TypeError: (0 , _lodash.get)(...).trim is not a function
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/dist/models.js:684:53
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at parseModelFunctions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/dist/models.js:680:9)
        at Models._callee4$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/dist/models.js:577:17)
        at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
        at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
        at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
        at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fakeit/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:35:14
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I expect the data to be shown on the console but I always get this error.

Comment: have you run an `npm install` before ?

Comment: Yes I did, the problem is solved .. it was just an indentation problem ! Thanks a lot

Comment: can you please edit your post to add the solution, could help somebody ;)